# How do I start Notepad++ from cmd?

Tags: command-line, windows-vista, notepad++

I can start the regular Notepad from cmd.

```
C:\Windows>notepad
```

I can also start it from the run prompt.

1. Win+R
2. notepad
3. Enter

I want to be able to do the same with the Notepad++. I can start it from the run prompt, but I can't start it from cmd.

I can also open a specific file in Notepad from cmd.

```
C:\Windows>notepad d:\mytext.txt
```

I want to be able to do the same with Notepad++.

Is this possible, and what can I do to enable this?

Comment: In Windows Vista, Windows 7, 8you can you can use start menu search box like run command. No need to press Win+R. Press Win and type in search box. Try it!

Comment: (Not enough rep to answer). If you want to open a file whose extension is associated to NotePad++, just type the full filename: `d:\mytext.txt` and it will be open in the default app. You cannot pass CL arguments, but quick enough if you just want to open  the file

Comment: You should check the answer from sudha jallu below, that one should be accepted as the answer for your question.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` to your `PATH` environment variable.

For example, you could run the following on the command prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
```

For further options, see [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Now I can do `notepad++ %userprofile%\desktop\testfile.txt` which is nice. I used the Environment Variables dialog box for this. What's the syntax for removing an environment variable using the set command? I couldn't find any specific switches or syntax for this. Not on the link you provided and not on the Computer Hope website.

Comment: @Sammy: Removing a single directory from the `PATH` variable is best done through the GUI, I assume. I don't know how to quickly remove it from the command line. If you want to *completely* remove an environment variable, you can use `set something=`, but I wouldn't advise you to do that for `PATH`.

Comment: I found a [path](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true) command. I understand I'm supposed to use semi colon to delete a path in the PATH variable?... I'm not sure how.

Comment: Using `path ;` clears the search path settings for the current instance of cmd. It doesn't actually remove the search paths from the PATH variable. By opening a new cmd window the search path settings are restored. Oh well, I guess I will use the GUI then.

Comment: This is worth noting: "Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session." This can be found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html). And it says that Set command is used to display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. So Set command can be used to remove the whole variable, in this example the PATH variable. And again, it will not be permanently removed from Windows. It is only valid for the duration of the CMD session. To _permanently_ set an environment variable _from_ CMD, the **Setx** command should be used instead. Either that or GUI.

Comment: Lots of good info here, thanks @Sammy and Oliver Salzburg

Comment: @Jikag You're welcome. I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 186):

Even though the Notepad++ directory is not in your path, you can use the command below to run the program from the command prompt:

```
start notepad++
```

To open a file in Notepad++, run:

```
start notepad++ <filename>
```

Comment: Not only this answers the original question, this is a very clever workaround that works immediately without having to setup anything. Worked great for me.

Comment: Love it.  Adding everything to the PATH is a horrible solution on windows.  What isn't clear is where START searches to find possible commands if it isn't the path.  Is it looking through the stuff installed in the start menu?

Comment: and it works also if you are in a cygwin shell: cygstart notepad++

Comment: Awesome! I use this after search some string with `findstr /spim /c:"SomeString" *.*`.

Comment: @user10550 I'm pretty sure Start references stuff in Libraries `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows` where as the $PATH variable is much different. You can actually specify what Start -> search references. [More Detail](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Folder-to-the-Windows-7-File-Index)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, every now and then, why touch the PATH variable

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I hope the OP read this.

Comment: This REALLY should be the accepted answer.  This is the cleanest answer on this page.

Answer (score 21):

I would not want to clutter my `PATH` just for using a single tool.

One alternative is to use an alternative text editor as 100% replacement for `Notepad` as explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/) with many details. Another description with a dedicated editor launcher tool can be found [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/replace-microsoft-notepad-with-latest-notepad-v50-in-windows/). Another `Notepad++` launcher on [github](https://github.com/przemoc/npplauncher/downloads).

A less invasive alternative is a `cmd` file like this:

```
"C:\Programme\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

This file has to reside somewhere along the existing `PATH`.
I actually put all my tools in one common `UTIL` directory, which is part of `PATH`.

Comment: What do you mean by "cmd file"? And what's with the asterisk and the percent sign? What file has to reside "along" the PATH? (It's not like it's going somewhere.) How do you make use of UTIL? Last time I checked there is no variable called UTIL. Is this something you came up yourself and added manually to the system? Can you explain any of this? And maybe give me some concrete example I can work with and hopefully learn from? Or are you just here to brag about how you know command line? I don't mean to be rude or anything, I'm just saying how it is. We all have different skill levels.

Comment: A cmd file could be the text script file npp.cmd which has the command as single text line inside. If you create a directory c:\util and put the script file into it, extend your PATH by c:\util, you from then on can call Notepad++ by typing "npp". %* stands for "all commandline arguments".

Comment: A cmd file is often called a "batch file".  In the days of MS-DOS, the extension was always `.BAT` but these days it is often `.cmd`.  The commands in the file are executed by `cmd.exe` which is the command-line shell itself.

Comment: Please note that in PowerShell the syntax for updating the PATH Environment Variable is a little different http://stackoverflow.com/a/1333717/47226

Comment: It looks like your link to the article on how to replace Notepad is broken already.

Comment: @RobH: Thanks for the hint. Is the fix ok for you?

Comment: That one works. (Of course, according to that article, the techniques that it describes don't work for Notepad++ due to how sophisticated it has become.)

Comment: @RobH: I keep trying to make my readers happy. Do you have links which I should include?

Comment: Nope. I was merely pointing out something that I noticed in the article.

Answer (score 13):

This is what I have done, in this way you dont have to type `notepad++`
Create `np.bat` file with this set of commands

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

place `np.bat` file in `c:\Windows`

open the command prompt and type `np` or `np myfile.txt` and enter.

Comment: Using start "" to prefix the command here prevents locking up the command prompt if a notepad++.exe is not already running.

Comment: i created an 'edit.bat' file with the contents : 'start notepad++ %1' - does just what i need to edit in the context of a cmd session.

Answer (score 7):

Combining the answers from Axel Kemper and adding some extra's, here is what I did to make a permanent command that you can give any name you want.

First of all I created an extra folder. In my case: **"C:\Users\Hansel\CmdFiles"**. In this folder I created a new text file throught the right click menu -> new -> text document. Edit the text document using notepad or notepad++ and type the following code in the .txt file:

```
@echo off
"C:\Software\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

Then you have to rename the file to your personal command, for example "npp.cmd".

> On a side note: the *@echo off* prevents the command from printing to
>   the command prompt;
>
> the link between the quotation marks can refer to any executable;
>
> *%** will make sure that anything you type after the
>   *npp* command (for example "*npp nonsense.txt*") will be put after the original command in the quotation marks.

Then you need to edit an "environment variable", in this case the so called PATH (this variable contains the folders where Windows looks for commands and executables). To add the folder to your PATH, push the windows button to enter the start menu and type *"edit environment variables for your account"*. Under "User variables for Hansel", create a new "Path" variable if it does not exist or edit the old "Path" variable if there is one.

If you make a new PATH variable, the variable value should just read: **C:\Users\Hans\CmdFiles**

If you edit an old PATH variable, the variable value should read: ***oldstuff*;C:\Users\Hans\CmdFiles**  *(mind the semi colon)*.

Windows now looks for commands in the folder **"C:\Users\Hansel\CmdFiles"** and you can easily add new commands to this folder!

Comment: You don't need `@ECHO OFF` for a one-line command. The `@` suppresses echo for that line alone, so `@"C:\Software\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*` does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to run any program installed on Windows from command is:

1. Find the location of notepad++.exe, create a shortcut under the installation directory.
2. cut and paste the shortcut to C:/windows/system 32.
3. Now you can press 'Win + R' and type the name of shortcut. All done.

PS: in my case, I named the shortcut 'notepadpp' (or even 'nppp') so that I don't have to press 'shift + =' twice for '+' symbol

Extremely simple and easy, and it's easy to delete the shortcut. You don't even need to change the path, registry

Comment: why `nppp` and not `npp`? you could type a `p` less every time

Answer (score 2):

Add the program directory to your [PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make a change to this registry key:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Notepad++.exe]`

You can download a zipped .reg file from [Donn Felker](http://www.donnfelker.com/running-notepad-from-the-command-line/) that lets you open a file with just an `n` shortcut.

I edited the .reg before running it and to make sure the path to Notepad++ is correct (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)`) and I also changed the shortcut to `n` instead of `n`.

Then double click to add to your registry.

Answer (score 2):

To run any program from command line with a short name you can create an alias for it by the command `doskey`:

```
doskey alias="drive:\path to program\executable" $*
```

For example, after running command
`doskey notepad++="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" $*`
you can open the text file with notepad++ by `notepad++ textfile`. Of course, you can use shorter alias something as `npp` or `n++`.

Also you can create alias for some path you often open:

```
doskey home=cd C:\Users\myprofile
```

But unfortunately you cannot use this alias in path. If you run `doskey home=C:\Users\myprofile` and then enter in the command line `cd home` or `start home\myfile` you receive error message.

To create your aliases automatically each time when `cmd` runs you can put its into the batch file like `autorun.cmd` and set it in the registry entry:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

or

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

---

Links to the articles:
[Console Aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682057(v=vs.85).aspx)
[Command Processor\AutoRun](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: doskey alias is not remembered after the current command prompt session is closed. Can you confirm?

Comment: @NotepadPlusPlusPRO, as long as I remember - yes, doskey alias is not remembered. but you can add it to the autorun.cmd file, and it'll be created every time you run terminal. this is how it worked when I wrote this post. but now I have been using Linux for a long time and don't know if this behavior persists on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
$ENV:Path="$ENV:Path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notepad++** has quite a cult following.  And those people who like what Notepad++ can do will likely be frequent users of this program.  So it only makes sense for these people to want easy access to Notepad++ ... and put Notepad++ on the system Path.

And these are likely the same people who would want a script to start notepad++ with a keyboard shortcut:

```
^q::run "Notepad++.exe"
```