# Why can i start some apps from windows cmd and run, even though there are no path variables for them?

Tags: notepad++, cmd.exe

So I know about the PATH variable, but it's not there. Why can I type "notepad++" in cmd and it will work and how can make other apps work like this?

The question is not HOW to start it via win+r run, but WHY can I start it right after installation without putting notepad++ directory to path variable.

**EDIT1:**
Added screenshots for path variables

Current user:
[image: Current user]

System:
[image: System]

**EDIT2:**
[cmd echo %path%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaMa1.png)

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files\php-7.3.4-Win32-VC15-x64;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\deadman\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start Notepad++ from cmd?](https://superuser.com/questions/607379/how-do-i-start-notepad-from-cmd)

Comment: Use `echo %PATH%` in Command Prompt to inspect the *actual* contents of PATH.

Comment: If the path to Notepad++ does not exist in the Path variable that is the exact reason it isn't working the way you want it to work.

Comment: Well, as I have stated there is NO path variable for notepad++ directory, I can add screenshots if needed. Neither there is notepad++ shortcut in windows or system32 folders.

Comment: @Ramhound well it works. and that's the reason i'm asking about it. Why does it?

Comment: @ymdred16 Is it possible that you have different paths defined in an administrator vs. non-admin command prompt?

Comment: @ymdred16 Also, this may be an obvious question, but do you happen to be in the same folder that notepad++ is in when you start it?

Comment: Please provide screenshots.

Comment: @raphael75 1) how do i check it? 2) no, i've tried running it from anywhere and it seems to work.

Comment: @Ramhound added screenshots for path variables

Comment: Again: Please use `echo %PATH%`. Also, use `where notepad++` to see where it is picked up. Only then can we start to check where this folder is added to `%PATH%`.

Comment: @DanielB added screenshot and text from "echo %path%". Also `where notepad++` results in "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

Comment: If you do a search on your harddrive(s) for notepad++.exe, is it possible that it's in one of those folders? It seems like even though you may have it installed in the default location that somehow the executable got copied to one of the folders that's in the path.

Comment: @raphael75 Definitely not. Just have checked every folder stated in any environment variable.

Comment: @ymdred16 I wonder if there may be a shortcut file that it's finding? I'm running out of ideas. :) What version of windows are you using?

Comment: @raphael75 win10 latest update, no shortcuts) i can also run opera, chrome and some other apps this way too. Wondering how it works.

Comment: Could you try doing a search on .lnk files (those are the shortcut files)? It's possible there are .lnk files for all the programs you're able to run in one of the paths in the PATH environment variable. Right now I can't think of anything else that would make this work.

Comment: seems like i found the answer, thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mose likely because some apps and programs add their paths to registry.
[Here](https://superuser.com/a/494548/1036040) you can find more about searching order for starting apps via cmd or `win+r`.
These paths are stored in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths**
[Here](http://HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%5CSOFTWARE%5CMicrosoft%5CWindows%5CCurrentVersion%5CApp%20Paths) you can find more about application registration on Microsoft docs.